# Is there a module/Drush command for updating multiple field settings at once?

Tags: entities, drush

Just for convenience I wish change all required fields to optional at once.

Is there module or even better, a Drush command supporting module to do so?

Comment: You mean all, on all content types?

Comment: yes. In my case these custom content types hold similar requests starting workbench workflows. It would for convenience but might be a nice-to-have in other use cases too.

Comment: @groovehunter That's a very unusual use case (bulk-updating field attributes across all entities/bundles doesn't make sense in most scenarios as their use is so disperate) so I doubt anything will already exist. You could write your own pretty easily using `field_info_fields()` and `field_info_instances()`

Comment: okay thanks for the hint, - 
and I agree that my case is unusual..

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there's a module or anything to do this, as it's quite a specific use case.

However, you could try something like the following in either a custom module's update/install hook.

***Note*** I've not tested this, but you'll have to tweak it for your use case anyway.

```
$options = array(
  'entity_type' => 'node'
);
// Get all field instances that are on nodes
$fields = field_read_instances($options)

// Loop through the fields...
foreach ($fields as $field => $data) {
  // ...and prune the array to remove any non-required fields
  if ($data['required'] == 0) {
    unset($fields[$field]);
  }
  // $fields now only contains data for required fields attached to nodes
}

// Loop through the remaining fields
foreach ($fields as $field) {
  $instance = array(
    // Provide the default information that field_update_instance requires
    'entity_type' => $field['entity_type'],
    'bundle' => $field['bundle'],
    'field_name' => $field['field_name'],
    // Make your required changes
    'required' => 0
  );

  // Take the data in the $instance array and pass it through to field_update_instance.
  field_update_instance($instance);
}
```

You can filter down your selection of fields by passing different options through to `field_read_instances()` (e.g. if you only want fields attached to the Basic Page content type, the `$options` array would look like this:

```
$options = array(
  'entity_type' => 'node',
  'bundle' => 'page'
);
```

As a sidenote, `field_update_instance` clears the field cache at the end of every call, so if you have a lot of fields, then this might take a while .

**Documentation:**

- [`field_read_instances();`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.crud.inc/function/field_read_instances/7)
- [`field_update_instance();`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.crud.inc/function/field_update_instance/7)

Comment: Ugh. I just saw @Clive comment above, and I forgot about `field_info_instances`, so that might be a better option for getting the initial list of fields.

Comment: Main difference is `field_read_instances()` bypasses cache and goes straight for the DB table - either one's fine really

Comment: @clive I always forget about `field_info_instances`. The function name `field_read_instances` just seems to make so much more sense so I don't forget that one ;-)

Comment: @Clive when one wants to write to the database basing on field info, I'd recommend `read` over `info` to avoid saving back obsolete data. Not a big risk in reading from cache, but on operations like this speed is not quite important, and data safety sure is.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [Required Fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/required_fields) module:

> This project provides an admin interface which lists all the fields
>   grouped under content types. And it has a functionality to make the
>   fields as required or optional.